# Distribution of sum of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Here's a small problem I tried to solve. 2 dice are thrown, let $X$ denote the result of the first dice and let $Y$ denote the result of the second dice. I'm asked to describe the law of $Z=X+Y$.

I tried to solve this problem using the law of total probabilities using the partition given by the events $\{ X=i \}$, for $i=1,2,...,6$. Now let $j \in \{ 1,2,3,...,11,12 \}$, then

\begin{align*}
P(Z=j) &=\sum_{i=1}^6 P(Z=j\mid X=i)P(X=i)\\
                     &=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^6 P(X+Y=j\mid X=i)\\
                     &=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^6 P(Y=j-i\mid  X=i)\\
                     &=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^6 P(Y=j-i).
\end{align*}

I cannot justify the last step. I just found out that it leads to the correct answer. I guess that it has something to do with the fact that the variables $X$ and $Y$ are independant.

In my book the definition of independant variables is the following :
$X$ and $Y$ are said to be independant iff for all $i,j$ the events $\{X=i\}$ and $\{Y=j\}$ are independant, i.e.
$$ P(X=i,Y=j)=P(X=i)P(Y=j). $$

Also I guess that $P(X=i,Y=j)$ means $P(\{X=i\} \cap \{Y=j\})$. Can anyone explain why I am allowed to write :

$$ P(Y=j-i\mid  X=i)=P(Y=j-i). $$

Are the two events $\{ Y=j-i\}$ and $\{ X=i \}$ independant ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is one definition of independent events:  $P(A\,|\,B)=P(A)$.

Comment: Thanks for your kinf comment. I simply don't see why the events $A=\{ Y=j-i \}$ and $B=\{ X=i \}$ are independant. I mean $A$ depent explicitly from $i$ and so does $B$. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: The value of the second die has nothing to do with the value of the first, nor do the probabilities depend on the value of $i$ (since the die comes up $\{1,\cdots, 6\}$ with equal probability).

Comment: Worth noting:  this would not be true if the dice were weighted.  Then $P(Y=j-i)$ would indeed depend on the value $i$.  You could still work the problem out, but the answer would be a lot messier.

Comment: Of course ! I understand now. Thanks a lot. I had trouble simply because $i$ shows up in the two expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X,Y$ are independent random variables then: $$P(X\in A,Y\in B)=P(X\in A)P(X\in B)$$ for **all** Borel measurable sets $A,B$.

Using that we find:

$$P(Y=j-i\mid X=i)=\frac{P(Y=j-i,X=i)}{P(X=i)}=\frac{P(Y=j-i)P(X=i)}{P(X=i)}=$$$$P(Y=j-i)$$

where the second equality rests on independence.